# Set java script value to php session and get session value onto another php file

Tags: javascript, php, session-cookies

I'm trying to set the JavaScript value to a PHP Session variable and get this session value to another php page.
here my code. 
on the same it will show the value using alert.
here's my first page index_1.php

```
 <Script>
  function(no_user){
   `var num_user = no_user;
    '<?php $_SESSION["num_user"] = "' + no_user+ '"; ?>';
     //alert('<?php echo $_SESSION["num_user"] ?>');*/
    window.open("demo.php"); 
  }
 </script>
```

another page index_2.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['num_user'])){
$a = $_SESSION['num_user'];
echo "Number of user: ". $a;

?>
```

Comment: It's Strange !!. Go with Ajax don't combine `js` with `php`

Comment: you can't mix javaScript and php as you do... and do you even run your function, I don't think so, because it is anonymous

Comment: can you please tell me how ajax will work or give any related link

Comment: Here is the tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

You can not set php variable in js try to set it another location(demo.php)

```
 <script>
  function(no_user){
   var num_user = no_user;
   window.open("demo.php?no_user="+no_user); 
   //or window.location = 'index2.php?no_user'+no_user;
  }
 </script>
```

and set session on demo.php/index2.php

```
session_start();
if(!empty($_GET['no_user'])) {
  $_SESSION['num_user']= $_GET['no_user'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to set session_start() in all PHP.Files before accessing $_SESSION-Variables and you're fine. PHP will automagically take care of re-using that session in other .php-files (same server, same domain etc.).